# No such property: GormEncryptedStringType when installing jasypt in grails

Tags: grails, plugins, encryption, jasypt

I'm trying to use `Jasypt plugin` on my `grails project`. I followed the setup described on the [wiki](https://bitbucket.org/tednaleid/grails-jasypt/wiki/Home) but I got the following exception:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [domain.Branch]:  No such property: GormEncryptedStringType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
Message: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [domain.Branch]:  No such property: GormEncryptedStringType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
```

Does any body have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post your domain class? It seems that you declared the type of your field as `GormEncryptedStringType` instead of `String`.

Comment: @Andrew would you add your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be as simple as a missing import line:

```
import com.bloomhealthco.jasypt.GormEncryptedStringType
```

Comment: i've added this line to my project, but it says that the GromEncryptedStringType cannon be resolved. If i put .* instead of that, then there are no errors. I've read somewhere that it is deprecated. What is the solution now?